# Bring UAC window to top using ShellExecuteEx()

Tags: c, winapi, uac, shellexecuteex

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 and I am writing my code in C/C++.

I have code which automatically starts my installation process. Installation process requires UAC in this case, so I use `ShellExecuteEx()` API function with `runas` verb:

```
hWindow = InstallCreateWindow(NULL);

execInfo.cbSize         = sizeof(execInfo);
execInfo.lpVerb         = _strdup("runas");
execInfo.hwnd           = hWindow;
execInfo.lpFile         = szPath;
execInfo.lpParameters   = szParams;
execInfo.fMask          = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS | SEE_MASK_FLAG_NO_UI;

Sleep(1000);

SetActiveWindow(hWindow);

if(ShellExecuteEx(&execInfo))
    return execInfo.hProcess;

if(GetLastError() == ERROR_CANCELLED)
{
    // user answered NO to UAC prompt
}
```

`InstallCreateWindow()` function creates information window and it also creates separate window message thread. Window is visible, topmost and it responds to messages. I have to create it because I've read that correct `hwnd` parameter in `SHELLEXECUTEINFO` structure is required to keep UAC prompt window on top.

But this does not work. Sometimes UAC window runs maximized, but mainly it is minimized and highlighted in the taskbar. Is there a method to bring UAC window to top in any case?

Comment: If the program that called `ShellExecuteEx` does not have foreground activation, then the UAC dialog cannot take activation, so it has to wait until the use activates it.

Comment: You're leaking the string you `_strdup`.

Comment: @JonathanPotter it is for test, I'll remove it.

Comment: @RaymondChen what does foreground activation means? My window is topmost. Do I need to call `SetForegroundWindow()` on it?

Comment: @RaymondChen, OK, I found your article about foreground activation permission. So, If I call `ShellExecuteEx()` when user clicks (or does some other activity) on my window, I can get UAC window on top?

Comment: It's missing `execInfo.nShow = SW_SHOWNORMAL`, and what's the purpose of `SetActiveWindow(hWindow);` and `Sleep(1000)`

Comment: @BarmakShemirani UAC window is independent from `SW_SHOWNORMAL`, isn't it? `SetActiveWindow(hWindow)` is for test, `Sleep(1000)` waits until window is initialized :) of course later I'll do it with events.

Comment: @RaymondChen I wrote code which calls `ShellExecuteEx()` when user clicks on a button in my window, and it works now, thank you very much!

Comment: C/C++ isn't a language.

Comment: @Insane I know. But when I say that I write in C, some people say it is not C because I use `.cpp` file extension and can use C++ features. When I say that I write in C++, they say that could not see any C++ features such as classes and templates. So to avoid misunderstanding I say that I write in C/C++, which means "mainly in pure C, using `.cpp` files".

Comment: You are writing in C++

Comment: @deselect Mainly in C using C++ is a way of saying C++ without C++ features :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**JUST TO MARK IT AS ANSWERED**

> If the program that called ShellExecuteEx does not have foreground
>   activation, then the UAC dialog cannot take activation, so it has to
>   wait until the use activates it.  Raymond Chen